# syntax for foreach in php

Tags: php, foreach

what does this syntax means in php

`foreach ( $meta as $t => $data )`

what does $t => $data mean in the above.

because foreach is basically (example from w3school)

```
  <?php
  $colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow");
  foreach ($colors as $value)
    {
    echo "$value <br>";
    }
  ?>
```

it the above case $value represents `$t => $data`

`$colors` represents `$meta`

the array $meta is as follows

```
    $meta = Array(
    'facebook' => Array(
      'title'   => 'og:title',
      'type'   => 'og:type',
      'url'   => 'og:url',
      'thumbnail'  => 'og:image',
      'width'   => 'og:image:width',
      'height'  => 'og:image:height',
      'sitename'  => 'og:site_name',
      'key'   => 'fb:admins',
      'description' => 'og:description'
    ),
    'twitter' => Array(
      'card'   => 'twitter:card',
      'description' => 'twitter:description',
    )
      );
```

then what is $t and what is $data

also if i want to get 'title' in 'facebook' as a seprate key how to do it. ie. will

```
  $t => $data => $final work

  $t = facebook or twitter
  $data = title etc
  $final = og:title etc
```

Comment: $t => $data mean like array $key=>$value

Comment: `$t` stands for key of an array. Read [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for more details.

Comment: its not greater than equal to symbol

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi - nope. It has a different meaning.

Comment: Frankly, you'd do much better to find some place *other* than w3schools to learn PHP.  The actual [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php) is quite useful; it has examples for just about everything, including [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `foreach` it loops over array's items. Base syntax is:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
  // first loop:  $item=foo
  // second loop: $item=bar
}
```

you can use extended syntax

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {}
```

which allows you to get item's key in `$key` variable. For example:

```
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  // first loop:  $key=0, $item=foo
  // second loop: $key=1, $item=bar
}
```

`$array` does not contain keys, so in `$key` variable you have numbers (starts with `0`).

If keys are defined (associative arrays), `$key` will take defined key value:

```
$array = array('key1' => 'foo', 'key2' => 'bar');
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
  // first loop:  $key=key1, $item=foo
  // second loop: $key=key2, $item=bar
}
```

Comment: you are using $key = $item, then what is the difference between $key => $item

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi That was a mistake, sorry - I've edited my answer.

Comment: just recheck my question. I have shown the array with 2 nests. what will the code

Answer (score 1):

$t => $data  means

$t       - Index (key)

$data    - value

Comment: True, but I guess the more common term for the index is key, key => value.

Comment: see my edited question. what if the array is a nested array, can we get multiple keys

Comment: Not pointless. It's clear enough for people who know ANY language. ;) But our OP is not such one..

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi It is clear that a foreach will loop the array contents,if you loop your example array $t should contain its key,and $data will contain array

Answer (score 1):

Read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php , attention on examples.

```
/* foreach example 3: key and value */

$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "\$a[$k] => $v.\n";
}

/* foreach example 4: multi-dimensional arrays */
$a = array();
$a[0][0] = "a";
$a[0][1] = "b";
$a[1][0] = "y";
$a[1][1] = "z";

foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

PS: If you coding using php read official manual not 'all-around-sites'.

**ADDED**

```
$a = array(
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "seventeen" => 17
);

foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    echo "$k => $v";
    // will show
    // one => 1two => 2three => 3
}

foreach ($a as $v) {
    echo "$v";
    // will show 
    // 12317
}
```

So, if we use $k (in our foreach()) we have 'key' name. In $v we always have 'value'.

**ADDED**

```
    $meta = Array(
        'facebook' => Array(
            'title' => 'og:title',
            'type' => 'og:type',
            'url' => 'og:url',
            'thumbnail' => 'og:image',
            'width' => 'og:image:width',
            'height' => 'og:image:height',
            'sitename' => 'og:site_name',
            'key' => 'fb:admins',
            'description' => 'og:description'
        ),
        'twitter' => Array(
            'card' => 'twitter:card',
            'description' => 'twitter:description',
        )
    );

    foreach ($meta as $sKey => $aValue) {
        // $sKey == 'facebook'
        // $aValue = array()
        // $aValue['title'] == 'og:title' 

        foreach ($aValue as $sKeyInner => $sValue) {
            // $sKeyInner == 'title'
            // $sValue == 'og:title'
        }
    }
```

That's all, I give up. XD

Comment: Copying the documentation verbatim is not an answer. Neither was just linking to it.

Comment: This is basic thing of ALL languages. How you can describe it without examples from manual? Telepathically? It described in ANY php for dummies (book), if TS didn't read this how we can describe it?

Comment: I realize that you're just trying to help the OP but if all you were planning to do is point them to the docs a comment would have been best.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax allows you to iterate over all items and also have the key of the array handy.

Taking a look at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), this syntax is explained best as follows:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

> ...[this syntax] will additionally assign the current element's key to the $key variable on each iteration.

In your example, the key will be the elements index within the array.

Answer (score 0):

In your example it means $meta is an array, and $t is the array keys and $data is the value of the keys.
For example, $t could be 3 and $data "yellow"

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of arrays in php

1. Normal arrays
2. Associative arrays

**For normal array:**

```
 <?php
      $colors = array("red","green","blue","yellow");
      foreach ($colors as $value)
        {
        echo "$value";   // prints  red,green...
        }
      ?>
```

**For Associative array:**

Eg : Array ( [0] => Array ( [Bookcode] => 124 [Bookname] => asd ) 
             [1] => Array ( [Bookcode] => 125 [Bookname] => asd )
           )

```
<?php 
foreach($arr as $key => $val)
        {
           echo $key;             //prints--> 124
           echo $val;             //prints -->asd
        }

?>
```