# Display durations, prices of my array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display the prices with my array :

1, 3, 6 are the duration and 10,25,50 are the price .

Did i do something wrong ?

I cant't see the durations and the prices , i used a foreach and i declared $duration as an array .

```
<?php
$suscribe = array(
    'prices' => array(
        1=>10,
        3=>25,
        6=>50,
        )
    );

$suscribe=array();

foreach($suscribe as $key=>$value)
    {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: You overwrite your array with an empty one $suscribe=array();

Comment: And you would need to correct to foreach($suscribe['prices']

Comment: And FYI: *suscribe* is misspelled. I assume you meant *subscribe*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Can Has Cheezburger** and **Gautam3164** gave you correct answer.
Simply change

```
foreach ($suscribe['prices'] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

Read more about array and foreach here [syntax for foreach in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835667/syntax-for-foreach-in-php/22835760#22835760)

Answer (score 1):

First, remove this, since this makes your array empty after declaration:

```
$suscribe=array();
```

And your for loop should be:

```
foreach($suscribe['prices'] as $key=>$value)
    {
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> $suscribe=array();

You have redeclared the $subscribe variable.

Answer (score 0):

First remove the line

```
$suscribe=array();
```

And for your `foreach` loop use like

```
foreach($suscribe['prices'] as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key.' : '.$value.'<br>';
}
```